# I am trying to validate my form with jquery plugins but remove class Not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```
<script>
    $(".form").validate({
        //...   
    });
    jQuery.validator.removeclass("classname", {remove});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$('form#myform').validate({

        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).removeClass("error");
        }
});
```

Comment: That's what the plugin already does by default!  Actually, `unhighlight` would be to remove the `error` class.